# ASP.NET 5 MVC6 User.GetUserId() returns incorrect id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I have simple project in ASP.NET 5 with one registered user. I have tried to get id of current logged user by extension method `GetUserId()` from `using System.Security.Claims` namespace. 
Unfortunately this method returns me not existing id and i don't know why.

Here is my simple code:

```
var currentUserId = User.GetUserId();
```

Method result:

[image]

Database:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cookies, cache and trying again? Maybe you're getting an old auth cookie?

Comment: Every time I saw this issue - it was cache/cookies issue. Open a private session in your browser and try debugging there.

Comment: @enki.dev Thank you, probably that was problem with cache. But i dont understand why I was able to log in as non existing user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely you're getting an *old* auth ticket that is still valid OR your getting an authentication ticket for another site your running locally. I would clear the browser cache and cookies and run it again.

Also, Try changing the name of the cookie, by default it is set to `.AspNet.Cookies` which can cause issues if you're running multiple apps locally. This caught me up a while back.

The cookie name can be changed like this

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => manager.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(user))
    },
    CookieName = "myAuthCookie",
});
```

The MSDN documentation on it can be [found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.cookiename(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions.CookieName).

Comment: I'm trying to implement your answer but I'm stuck See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319492/how-to-set-the-cookie-validateinterval-in-asp-net-core