# How to set the cookie validateInterval in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

I'm trying to set the `validateInterval` for an ASP.NET 5 RC1 application which makes use of `ASP.NET Identity 3`

I am trying to implement the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463706/asp-net-5-mvc6-user-getuserid-returns-incorrect-id) answer.

there are many code sample like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300101/asp-net-identity-not-persisting-cookie-mvc6-vnext/35302926#35302926) but it seems it isn't valid in ASP.NET 5 RC1

```cs
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15))
    },
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
});
```

If I try use the above code example in `ASP.NET 5 RC1` I can't as

`Provider` is not a property of `CookieAuthenticationOptions`
and Visual studio cannot locate `CookieAuthenticationProvider` in any namespace via its lightbulb options.

How do I set the `validateInterval` in `ASP.NET 5 RC1`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of ASP.NET Core 2.0 you won't be able to set `SecurityStampValidationInterval` when you `AddIdentity`.

You'll be able to set the `ValidationInterval` via `SecurityStampValidatorOptions`:

```
        services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        });
```

P.S: You'll have to `AddIdentity` first and `ConfigureApplicationCookie` after.

Comment: Works in ASP.NET Core 6. A small sidenote. I had overwritten the CookieAuthenticationEvents in CookieAuthenticationOptions with new CookieAuthenticationEvents and as a result SecurityStamp validation was not performed anymore, because OnValidatePrincipal is registered in AddIdentity. So make sure not to set a new CookieEvents instance, but rather assign specific Funcs if required. Took me a while... ;(

Comment: @DiegoFrehner thank you, just ran into this. I chose slightly different solution. My custom CookieAuthenticationEvents implementation takes the existing ones as argument in the constructor and copies all the delegates into itself before replacing the original

Answer (score 9):

The validation interval is set in IdentityOptions:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
{
    options.SecurityStampValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
}
```

You can attach to the validation event using the CookieAuthenticationEvents:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
    {
        OnValidatePrincipal = context =>
        {
            Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync(context);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        },
    },
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
});
```

Comment: or simply `return SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync(context);`